# Best way to get data into screen using react navigation screens. Error using hook

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-hooks

I have a basic flat list of products that are getting rendered from a products array. Im using react navigation to navigate to a product detail screen but trying to think of the best way to get the active selected product so I can display the product information in the product detail page.

My Approach: I thought just use a hook to provide the active product and I tried that but for some reason I am not getting the proper state provided in the product detail page.

Getting the error: "TypeError: null is not an object (evaluating 'product.title')"

By the way for now I'm trying to avoid using redux as my school project is due tomorrow and also trying to learn hooks.

EDIT: Hmm I see now I can also use Route params. I think I would still really like to understand what is going on with my current hooks approach.

Product Card Component

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";

import {
  View,
  ImageBackground,
  Text,
  Pressable,
  StyleSheet,
  Button,
  Dimensions,
  ScrollView,
  RefreshControl,
  SafeAreaView,
  Image,
  FlatList,
  TouchableOpacity,
} from "react-native";

import { useQuery, gql } from "@apollo/client";

import Amplify, { Auth } from "aws-amplify";

import { createBottomTabNavigator } from "@react-navigation/bottom-tabs";
import { useNavigation, NavigationContainer } from "@react-navigation/native";
import useProduct from "../hooks/useProduct";

function ProductCard({ item }) {
  const navigation = useNavigation();
  const { setActiveProduct } = useProduct();

  const imgUrl = "http://192.168.1.252:3000" + item.media[0].URLs.thumbnail;
  const imgUrl2 = imgUrl.replace("thumbnail", "large");

  return (
    <TouchableOpacity
      style={styles.buttonContainer}
      onPress={() => {
        setActiveProduct(item);

        navigation.navigate("Product Detail");
      }}
    >
      <View style={styles.view}>
        <Image
          style={styles.productImage}
          source={{
            uri: imgUrl2,
          }}
        />
      </View>
    </TouchableOpacity>
  );
}

export default ProductCard;

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  buttonContainer: {
    flex: 0.5,
    margin: 5,
    backgroundColor: "white",
  },
  view: {
    flex: 1,

    display: "flex",
    flexDirection: "column",
    height: 200,
  },

  productImage: {
    width: "100%",
    height: "70%",
  },
  description: {
    width: "100%",
    height: "60%",
  },
});
```

Product Detail Page

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";

import {
  View,
  ImageBackground,
  Text,
  Pressable,
  StyleSheet,
  Button,
  Dimensions,
  ScrollView,
  RefreshControl,
  SafeAreaView,
  Image,
  FlatList,
  TouchableOpacity,
} from "react-native";

import useProduct from "../../hooks/useProduct";

function ProductDetailScreen() {
  const { product } = useProduct();

  if (!product) {
    return (
      <View>
        <Text>{product.title}</Text>
      </View>
    );
  }
  return (
    <View>
      <Text>{product.title}</Text>
    </View>
  );
}

export default ProductDetailScreen;
```

useProduct hook to manage my active product state

```
import React, { useState } from "react";

function useProduct() {
  const [product, setProduct] = useState(null);

  setActiveProduct = (newProduct) => {
    setProduct(newProduct);
  };

  return { product, setActiveProduct };
}

export default useProduct;
```

Comment: In **ProductDetailPage** `if(!product)` will return `product.title` before the product was initialize.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`useProduct()` returns separate state objects to both components. Try using `product` inside `ProductCard`. You will see the `product` updated in `ProductCard` component. But this `product` is not the same that is returned to `ProductDetailScreen`. Both components get separate state objects.

Comment: Im sorry im trying to understand your comment. So ProductCard doesn't need the product. The only purpose of the useProduct hook is to know which product was clicked. So in the product card nothing was clicked yet so we don't have a product at that moment.

I am now using routes params and its working great but I'm just trying to understand hooks and trying to learn why that approach was not working.

Comment: Simply, useProduct returns two different objects to both components. If you want to share data between two (or more) components, then you can use Context instead.